# How to pass cookies on ASP.NET request

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, request

I need to pass all my current page cookies to other server with request:

```
string url = "http://www.someserver.com/page1.aspx";
        // Create a request for the URL. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        //Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams and the response.
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
```

What should I add to this code to read current cookies and pass them to http://www.someserver.com/page1.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = 
    Request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie.ToString()];
```

where obviously the `Request` variable used here is an ASP.NET [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) instance.

Comment: I tried this, and it did nothing but pass in 1 item into Headers, which was "Cookie" and not all the cookies.  Just 1